# How do I set default cookie for referral if no $_GET found?

Tags: php, cookies

I want make a simple referral system. Basically referral URL structure something like this.

```
http://domain.com/?ref=abc
http://domain.com/about-us/?ref=abc
http://domain.com/slug/more-slug/?ref=abc
```

1. How do I validate if no cookie found, script will set default cookie to `$_COOKIE['referral'] = 'generic'`
2. If cookie already exists just keep it.

Here what I've done but it always replace to `generic` if no referral found although previously already having it.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['referral'])) {
    setcookie('referral', 'generic', time() + 31536000);
} else if (isset($_GET['ref']) && !empty($_GET['ref'])) {
    $ref = trim(secure($_GET['ref']));
    setcookie('referral', $ref, time() + 31536000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['referral'])){
    if(isset($_GET['ref']) && !empty($_GET['ref'])) {
        $ref = trim(secure($_GET['ref']));
        setcookie('referral', $ref, time() + 31536000);
    }else{
        setcookie('referral', 'generic', time() + 31536000);
    }
}
```

you could remove **isset($_GET['ref'])** cause you check **!empty($_GET['ref'])**